# box with bclogo

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, bclogo

I would like to know if there is a package or a method to achieve exactly the kind of box in the following image.

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Comment: Yes, `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Please provide the tags (`MWE`) what you tried to meet this output. And it is possible, by using `tcolorbox`, but I'm not sure about with `bclogo`

Comment: I believe that for the second point "Preuve" with zigzag we will need  `bclogo`.

Comment: No, `tcolorbox` can do it as well.

Comment: Ok, but how can i do for the second point : 'wavy vertical rule'  above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

## Implementing a style giving the desired layout

As said in the comments, this box style can be obtained with the powerful `tcolorbox`. I do this in two steps:

1. Define a `my box` style that can be applied to any `tcolorbox` and implements the design you want.
2. Use `\newtcolorbox` to define an environment called `mybox` that uses the `my box` style.

Of course, you can apply the `my box` style to other `tcolorbox`es if you want—that is the whole point of separating the two operations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{boxTitle}{HTML}{fff79a}
\definecolor{boxBackground}{HTML}{fffce0}
\definecolor{boxFrame}{HTML}{f1e2b8}

\tcbset{my box/.style={
    enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colback=boxBackground, colframe=boxFrame,
    coltitle=black, colbacktitle=boxTitle,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.3cm,
                                    yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
      before upper=\hspace*{0.5cm}, % reserve space for the image
      overlay={
       \node at ([xshift=0.5cm]frame.west)
         {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{bc-dodecaedre}};
      }
    }
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{my box, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[title={This is a great title, with a comma}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Note: the `bc-dodecaedre` graphics comes from the `bclogo` package, so you must have it installed in order to have the graphics (`.mps` file, obtained with MetaPost).

## Automatically numbered boxes

Following your request in a comment, here are several ways of creating independently-numbered series of boxes using the layout we developed in the previous section (reusing it is particularly easy thanks to the `my box` style). There are basically two ways:

- using `auto counter` in the first optional argument of `\newtcolorbox` (see the two box series defined in the example below: boxes of type A and boxes of type B);
- using the `theorems` library of `tcolorbox` (see the `theorem` environment defined in the example).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, theorems}
\usepackage{nameref}            % only needed if you use \nameref

\definecolor{boxTitle}{HTML}{fff79a}
\definecolor{boxBackground}{HTML}{fffce0}
\definecolor{boxFrame}{HTML}{f1e2b8}

\tcbset{my box/.style={
    enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colback=boxBackground, colframe=boxFrame,
    coltitle=black, colbacktitle=boxTitle,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.3cm,
                                    yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={
      before upper=\hspace*{0.5cm}, % reserve space for the image
      overlay={
       \node at ([xshift=0.5cm]frame.west)
         {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{bc-dodecaedre}};
      }
    }
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{countedboxa}[2][]{%
  my box, title={Counted box of type A~(\thetcbcounter): #2}, #1}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{countedboxb}[2][]{%
  my box, title={Counted box of type B.~(\thetcbcounter): #2}, #1}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{my box}{th}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}

\begin{countedboxa}[label={first box of type A}]{Some title}
  My number is~\thetcbcounter.
\end{countedboxa}

\begin{countedboxb}[label={first box of type B}]{Other title}
  Note the different numbering style due to our use of
  \verb|number within=section| for boxes of type~B. My number is~\thetcbcounter.
\end{countedboxb}

\begin{countedboxa}[label={second box of type A}]{Another title}
  My number is~\thetcbcounter. The third box of type A is number~\ref{third
    box of type A} on page~\pageref{third box of type A}.
\end{countedboxa}

\begin{countedboxb}[label={second box of type B}]{The title}
   My number is~\thetcbcounter. The third box of type B is number~\ref{third
    box of type B} on page~\pageref{third box of type B}.
\end{countedboxb}

\begin{theorem}{Compacity of Foo spaces}{foo}
% Text (mostly) from the tcolorbox manual
This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
in this example, prefixed with the section number due to our use of
\verb|number within=section|. This theorem is numbered \ref{th:foo}, found
on page~\pageref{th:foo} and titled ``\nameref{th:foo}.''
\end{theorem}

An immediate but very convenient consequence of this result is
theorem~\ref{th:bar}.

\begin{theorem}{Bar}{bar}
Trivial consequence of theorem~\ref{th:foo}.
\end{theorem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{countedboxa}[label={third box of type A}]{Some title}
  See boxes~\ref{first box of type A} and \ref{second box of type A} in
  section~\ref{sec:first}.
\end{countedboxa}

\begin{countedboxb}[label={third box of type B}]{Title of the box}
  See boxes~\ref{first box of type B} and \ref{second box of type B} in
  section~\ref{sec:first}.
\end{countedboxb}

\begin{theorem}{Quux}{quux}
This is a very important result.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image: Page 1]

---

Top of page 2:

[image: Top of page 2]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Is it possible to insert different counter? for example one for the definition another for the theorem ....

Comment: Please see the latest revision of my answer: I added several examples doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Dear frougon.                                                                                            I appreciate what you do , but i still have a question about the second point "Preuve" with zigzag

Comment: I already answered many questions here and you didn't even accept my answer (see “[How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)” in case you don't know what this means). Please ask a new question—this request is completely unrelated to the rest. On this site, we like specific, simple and clear, abstract questions, because this makes the answers much more useful to readers than please-write-my-whole-book questions.

Comment: For my tastes it is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for your point number 1, i.e., `shaded box with round corner`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\tikzset{titregris/.style =
{draw=black, thick, fill=yellow, %
text=black, rectangle, rounded corners, right,minimum height=.7cm}}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{theo}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt,linecolor=black]
\node[titregris,anchor=east,rectangle,fill=yellow!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[titregris,anchor=east,rectangle,fill=yellow!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=yellow,roundcorner=5pt,backgroundcolor=yellow!10,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options.

This is my own box with a mandatory title
and options following para.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

And regarding Point number 2, i.e., `wavy vertical rule` for text, not yet completed, may be some experts may give answer, meantime I'm also trying...

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.